# Events and Triggers for UI Controls in Enterprise Architect

Tags: enterprise-architect

Is there any possibilities for Assigning Events or Triggers to UI Controls for the User Interface Model in Enterprise Architect? My requirement is to link the UI models in the States and use the UI element triggers for making transitions.

Answer (score 1):

You would usually model a state machine for your controller class (context menu `Add/State Machine`). Within this state machine you can create those Events/Triggers. You can also create Actions from your class methods by dropping them onto the state diagram.

Comment: Hi Thomas, Thank you for the reply and clearing up the triggers assignment part. So it means there is no possibilty of using modeled UI element to trigger the tranistions.

Comment: The triggers are part of a state machine and this itself is part of a class for which it describes behavior. Sure you can place things where they do not belong. But why? The above is common sense. Maybe you can explain your reasons for that deviation?

Comment: Hi Thomas, Thanks again. I just found an answer after following the link http://www.sparxsystems.com.au/resources/demos/simulation_prototyping/simulation-prototype.htm. It is possible to trigger signals in the UI controls by tagging the controls with UIBroadcastSignal(signalName). My requirement is to create a statemachine simulation environment as in the demo using User interface model

Comment: Will try to reform my questions well from next time onwards.